# Progam CC26x2 with ST-Link V3PWR and OpenOCD

Tags: openocd, st-link

I want to connect the STlink V3PWR with CC26x2 from TI with OpenOCD. Therefore I tried the following command:

openocd.exe -f interface/stlink-dap.cfg -c "transport select dapdirect_jtag" -c "adapter speed 1000" -f target/ti_cc26x2.cfg

Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0 (2023-10-02) [https://github.com/sysprogs/openocd]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
libusb1 09e75e98b4d9ea7909e8837b7a3f00dda4589dc3
For bug reports, read
http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
dapdirect_jtag
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
cortex_m reset_config vectreset
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections Info : STLINK V4J2B1S0 (API v3) VID:PID 0483:3757 Info : Target voltage: 3.261539
Error: init mode failed (unable to connect to the target)

Any idea whats wrong? Or is it not possible?